# Separate two strings to two variables

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this :

```
var colors = 'Red,Blue,Green,Orange,White,Brown';
```

I tried to parse it to get all the colors which means :

```
color1='Red';
color2='Blue';
[...]
```

I used to use the `matches()` and then put a comma since the colors are separated by commas so I put ',', but the result is not what I've expected... Is there any fast way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any fast way to do it?

Yep, I recommend you to use `split()`

As the docs says :

> The split() method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array.
>
> Tip: If an empty string ("") is used as the separator, the string is split between each character.
>
> Note: The split() method does not change the original string.

So you could get the same of your colors doing something like this :

```
var colors = 'Red,Blue,Green,Orange,White,Brown'.split(','); //use .split() to split the character you want to.
var color1 = colors[0];
var color2 = colors[1];
var color3 = colors[2];
[...]
alert("Color 1 = " +color1 + "\n"+ "Color 2 =  " + color2);
```

Now you could do some logic to know the items that are on your `var colors` or whatever you want.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

If you dont mind to have it on the global object:

```
'Red,Blue,Green,Orange,White,Brown'.split(',').forEach(function(color, index ){
  window['color' + index] = color;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To match it with a regular expression you just need to use `\w+` which matches any of the following characters `A-Z a-z 0-9 _`.

```
var colors = 'Red,Blue,Green,Orange,White,Brown';
var matches = colors.match(/\w+/g);
console.log(matches[0]);
```

If you are worried about matching the numbers and underscore, you can always just use `/[a-z]+/gi`

Comment: Thanks for your opinion!

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code:

```
String [] stringParts = myString.split(":");
```